# Oracle Function Select * from Query Not giving any Results

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The following is the function definition I am using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MA_FACTSET.totalCustomers
RETURN number as
    total INTEGER := 0;
    FID VARCHAR2(30) := 'NT33H0-S-US';
    stmt varchar2(1000);

BEGIN
    execute immediate 'TRUNCATE TABLE MovingAverage';
    execute immediate 'DROP TABLE MovingAverage';
    execute immediate 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MovingAverage
    (ID INTEGER,
     PDATE DATE,
     PPRICE FLOAT,
     MA1 FLOAT) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS';

    stmt := 'INSERT INTO  MovingAverage (ID,PDATE,PPRICE) SELECT 
    ROWNUM,"DATE",P_PRICE FROM FP_BASIC_BD WHERE FS_PERM_SEC_ID = ''NT33H0-S-US''';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt);
    execute immediate stmt;
    dbms_output.put_line(SQL%ROWCOUNT);
    commit;

    execute immediate 'UPDATE  MovingAverage A SET MA1 =(SELECT AVG(PPRICE) 
    FROM MovingAverage WHERE ID>=A.ID-5 AND ID<A.ID )' ;
    dbms_output.put_line(SQL%ROWCOUNT);
    commit;

    execute immediate 'SELECT * FROM MovingAverage ORDER BY ID ASC';
    dbms_output.put_line(SQL%ROWCOUNT);
    commit;

    dbms_output.put_line(total);
    RETURN total;
END;
/
```

I have applied some checks to see whether the function is running properly or not, like getting `SQL%ROWCOUNT`.

The following is the DBMS output of the function:

```
INSERT INTO  MovingAverage (ID,PDATE,PPRICE) SELECT ROWNUM,"DATE",P_PRICE     FROM FP_BASIC_BD WHERE FS_PERM_SEC_ID = 'NT33H0-S-US'
4114
4114
0
0
```

I want know why rowcount of "`SELECT * FROM MovingAverage ORDER BY ID ASC`" is 0. And if there is any way to print complete table in Data Grid. I am using TOAD for Oracle.

Comment: You create a table but you don't drop it, so unless I am missing something it will fail the second time you call the function. It is better to create the tables you need at deployment and not at runtime.

Comment: @William Robertson I have created a GTT so that I don't waste my SPACE.

Comment: A GTT doesn’t take any space when not in use. Even a normal table only takes a trivial amount of space when empty. I wouldn’t worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With collections and the table function, a function can return a table that can be queried in an SQL statement. This is demonstrated in the following example.

**Create your record type variable first.**

```
create or replace type t_record as object (i number,n varchar2(30));
```

**Create table type variable which is based on record type variable.**

```
create or replace type t_table as table of t_record;
```

**Then we can proceed to create a function as follows.**

```
create or replace function return_table return t_table as
  v_ret   t_table;
begin

 --
 -- Call constructor to create the returned
 -- variable:
 --
v_ret  := t_table();

 --
 -- Add one record after another to the returned table.
 -- Note: the »table« must be extended before adding
 -- another record:
 --
    v_ret.extend; v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_record(1, 'one'  );
    v_ret.extend; v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_record(2, 'two'  );
    v_ret.extend; v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_record(3, 'three');

 --
 -- Return the record:
 --
    return v_ret;

end return_table;
```

**For more details and further extension of work please refer following URL.**

https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/Oracle/PL-SQL/collection-types/return-table-from-function/index

**http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/coll/return_table.html**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19874224)

Comment: Made the changes as you recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to rewrite your function removing dynamic sqls where not necessary. Also, If you have DDLs, DMLs don't use PL/SQL function, rather use procedure.

For `select` Statements in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, it will work if you use `BULK COLLECT INTO`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalCustomers
   RETURN NUMBER
AS
   total   INTEGER := 0;
   FID     VARCHAR2 (30) := 'NT33H0-S-US';
   stmt    VARCHAR2 (1000);

   TYPE mrectype IS TABLE OF MovingAverage%ROWTYPE;

   mrec    mrectype;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE MovingAverage';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE MovingAverage';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MovingAverage
(ID INTEGER,
 PDATE DATE,
 PPRICE FLOAT,
 MA1 FLOAT) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS';

   stmt :=
      'INSERT INTO  MovingAverage (ID,PDATE,PPRICE) SELECT 
ROWNUM,"DATE",P_PRICE FROM FP_BASIC_BD WHERE FS_PERM_SEC_ID = ''NT33H0-S-US''';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (stmt);

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQL%ROWCOUNT);
   COMMIT;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE  MovingAverage A SET MA1 =(SELECT AVG(PPRICE) 
FROM MovingAverage WHERE ID>=A.ID-5 AND ID<A.ID )';

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQL%ROWCOUNT);
   COMMIT;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM MovingAverage ORDER BY ID ASC'
      BULK COLLECT INTO mrec;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQL%ROWCOUNT);
   COMMIT;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (total);
   RETURN total;
END;
/
```

Call this function like this.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
x NUMBER;
BEGIN
x := totalCustomers;
END;
/
```

You cannot call the function in SQL `select`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's working for me. @KaushikNayak Awesome reply. I want to print the whatever no of rows are there in "mrec". Please help me regarding same.

Comment: @ShekharNalawade : Could you please elaborate your question. ?`SQL%ROWCOUNT` is already giving you the number of records,correct? `mrec` is a collection. So, to count the number of rows in `mrec` , you could use `mrec.COUNT` . ` If you want to fetch the records in the collection, you need to loop through it.

Comment: got your point. Great Help. I am trying to call this function as

    SELECT totalCustomers FROM DUAL;

but getting an error as folllows:-

**ORA-14552: cannot perform a DDL, commit or rollback inside a query or DML 
ORA-06512: at "MA_FACTSET.TOTALCUSTOMERS", line 12**

I am going to use this in excel VBA so its important for me that function runs froma select statement.

Comment: How can I use this in Excel VBA. Normal syntax to called function is **select function_nnem from dual;** That I can use in excel VBA, not the one you have said.

Comment: @ShekharNalawade : You may ask that as a separate question tagging vb and get answer from VBA experts.